# One URL which will direct to the correct store (based on location and language)

Tags: magento-1.9

**I know this isn't a very Magento question, but I'm hoping someone in the community has dealt with this.**

We have a multi-store setup with more than 10 stores (different languages and domains), which share many products between them.

The problem:

If we want to do a product promotion on say - Instagram, and include a product URL in the description, it would only be one store (obviously, its dumb to direct a Spanish customer to a Danish site), so:

**How to create a "universal" URL which will automatically redirect the customer to the correct store (based on location and language).**

Note: Our sites do have `hreflang` with `alternate hrefs` set up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Open Weather API. With that, you can detect the city and country. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/stefaleon/pen/NYWoom?page=1&).

After, you could do a [Strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) function on PHP to gather the variables, and do "if" conditions. After, you could do something like that:

```
$variable_with_all_countries = ['AR', 'BR', 'DE', 'EN'];
$strpos = strpos($country_name, $variable_with_all_countries);
if ($strpos === 'DE') { header('Location: http://www.yourcorrectsite.com/');  }
```

That's my suggestion. Let me know if you got it.